# Is there a better way to trim a circle from 0.1-0.9 following remaining time?

Tags: animation, swiftui, timer, geometry

This is my current working solution but it seems wonky. I kinda poked around with the numbers until it worked but I don't fully understand the math. Below is my code. The second circle `.trim` is were I think the main problem lies.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var timeRemaining: TimeInterval = 10
    @State private var startTime: Double = 10
    @State private var timer: Timer?
    @State private var isRunning: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .trim(from: 0.1, to: 0.9)
                .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 20, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(90))
                .opacity(0.3)
            
            Circle()
                .trim(from: 0.1, to: CGFloat((1.1 - (timeRemaining / (startTime) - 0.026)) / 1.25))
                .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 20, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(90))
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1))
            
            Text(formattedTime())
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .bold()
        }
        .frame(width: 250)
        
        Button {
            isRunning.toggle()
            if isRunning {
                startTimer()
            } else {
                stopTimer()
            }
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: isRunning ? "stop.fill" : "play.fill")
                .foregroundStyle(.foreground)
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .padding()
        }
    }
    
    private func startTimer() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { _ in
            if timeRemaining > 0 {
                timeRemaining -= 1
            } else {
                stopTimer()
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func stopTimer() {
        isRunning = false
        timer?.invalidate()
        timeRemaining = 10
        startTime = Double(timeRemaining)
    }
    
    private func formattedTime() -> String {
        let minutes = Int(timeRemaining) / 60
        let second = Int(timeRemaining) % 60
        return String(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes, second)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just make the animation run for the same time as the timer is counting down. It needs to be `linear` too.

In order for the dot to be visible at the start, the initial position must be anything larger than 0.1. 0.101 works fine.

```swift
Circle()
    .trim(from: 0.1, to: isRunning ? 0.9 : 0.101)
    .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 20, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
    .rotationEffect(.degrees(90))
    .animation(.linear(duration: isRunning ? timeRemaining : 0.5), value: isRunning)
```

[image: Animation]

Comment: Dang thanks. I clearly was overthinking the trim portion. I didn’t even consider animation timing.